# Set textbox of a usercontrol from another usercontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, textbox

I have usercontrol ctrlinserimento with a textbox and I have  another usercontrol ctrlricerca with a botton that should set textbox.text in ctrlinserimento to a string(let's say for example 'Hello').

How can I do?

ctrlinserimento

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication3
{
    public partial class ctrlinserimento : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {

   public string textbox1
    {

        set { TextBox1.Text = value; }
        get { return TextBox1.Text; }
    }


  }
}
```

ctrlricerca

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView;



namespace WebApplication3
{
public partial class ctrlricerca: System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public ctrlinserimento i
    {
        set; get;
    }


    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      i.textbox1 = "Hello";

      }
  }

 }

}
```

I have NullReferenceException on

```
i.textbox1 = "Hello";
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of way to do it i.e. page level, User control level. Check following solution that fit for you.

In ctrlricerca user control add property for ctrlinserimento and page level assign instance of ctrlinserimento to property of ctrlricerca

public partial class ctrlricerca: System.Web.UI.UserControl
{

```
private string nome;

public  ctrlinserimento { set; }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ctrlinserimento.textbox.text="Hello";  

  }


    }

}
```

}

Comment: what are the issues you are getting ? I could help you